# Combining Wordpress and Magento: Can Magento be installed on a subdomain with a store on another?

Tags: wordpress, magento, installation, subdomain

Trying to achieve the following structure for a new website, using Wordpress and Magento 2.1 (Community Edition) managing content and ecommerce separately, and benefiting from their respective strengths:

- **website.com**
  Domain root with multisite Wordpress installation
- **website.com/profiles**
  Page or post archive with Wordpress (easily done)
- **events.website.com**
  Subdomain with multisite Wordpress (achievable with Multisite Wordpress)
- **store.website.com**
  A subdomain with Magento installed
- **store2.website.com**
  A subdomain with a Magento store that shares the same installation as 'store.website.com'

The last thing is the one I am unsure about - is it possible to have Magento installed on one subdomain, for it to have a store on another subdomain 'sibling'?

I have looked at the documentation for Magento and couldn't find an answer for this.

If this is possible, any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!